# get .BAT file or SQLCMD to prompt user for input

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file, sqlcmd

I am attempting to run the following query

```
sqlcmd -STEMP7 -E -devolive_base -w256
    -QEXIT("DECLARE @r int EXEC @r = usp_AddToObservationtbl $,$,$ SELECT @r")
```

I am attempting to get the BAT file to ask the user for 3 variables.... can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set /p` to get variables:

```
set /p var1=Enter variable 1
set /p var2=Enter variable 2
set /p var3=Enter variable 3
```

...then use them in  your command line:

```
sqlcmd -STEMP7 -E -devolive_base -w256 -QEXIT("DECLARE @r int EXEC @r = usp_AddToObservationtbl %var1%,%var2%,%var3% SELECT @r")
```

Bear in mind this still leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks or someone entering something destructive.

Comment: this doesn't appear to work, the script exits without inserting any rows, I dont get any error file either

Comment: @chris - does it work if you put in the variables manually?  Also bear in mind if they are strings you will need to add single quotes to wrap them

Comment: if I substitute the $ symbols for values, it works. The variable setup does not work. I'm assuming this is because the values can't be passed into the SQLcmd program

Comment: @Chris - `sqlcmd` has a `-v`  parameter you can use to pass parameters to the called script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the comments people.

The problem appeared to be my syntax for SQLCMD is incorrect, but its not throwing an error, the variable substitution does work if I replace it with osql instead.  So this works fine

```
set /p var1= Enter Userid
set /p var2= Enter Casino Name  
set /p var3= Enter Screename 

osql -STEMP7 -E -devolive_base -w256 -QEXIT("DECLARE @r int EXEC @r = usp_AddToObservationtbl %var1%,%var2%,%var3% SELECT @r") -b -oc:\bat\observation.log
exit errorlevel
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example with the basic problem solved and specifics of your actual query removed.

I have removed  a command to change the Windows prompt and a command to turn echo off, as these were just used to beautify the output, not part of the solution. I've also used an underscore in the data input prompt where you would normally have a space, so that you can see it. I have left a `pause` at the end of the bat file, which is only necessary to see the output, in case you want to try it out yourself.

### test.bat

```
set /p batchvariable=Enter a number:_
sqlcmd -v sqlvariable=%batchvariable% -i test.sql
pause
```

### test.sql

```
SELECT $(sqlvariable) AS [result];
```

When you run the batch file, this is what you get.

[image: Result]

In practice you are likely to use the same names for the batch variable and the SQL variable. They are different above to illustrate what's what.

If you need to do this, you may need more than one variable. You handle this by repeating the `-v sqlvariablename=%batchvariablename%` part of the `sqlcmd`, e.g.

```
-v v1=%v1% -v v2=%v2%
```

### test.bat

```
set /p item=Item : 
set /p cost=Cost : 
sqlcmd -v item="%item%" -v cost=%cost% -i test.sql
```

### test.sql

```
SELECT '$(item)' AS [item], $(cost) AS [cost];
```

**Note that there are quotes added into this second example** (for string data) which didn't appear in the first example (with numerical data only).

You might want to run the example with `Box of Chocolates` for the item field and check the behavior.

[image: Another example]